# where is my zendframework library is in ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu

I had install zend framework on ubuntu and it was install properly. but now i want to change php.ini include_path but i don't where is my zend framework library is located in my ubuntu system , how can i know or find where is my zend framework folder is installed .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely will be in /usr/share/zend/, /usr/share/php/, or /usr/local/zend/.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in Ubuntu 12.04 you can find it on:

/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php

Answer (score 1):

In general, the *Synaptics Package Manager* can show precisely which files (and their paths) were installed:

System > Administration > Synaptics Package Manager > [my-package] > Properties > Installed Files

Answer (score 0):

You can just type a command in ubunto "which php" this will give you tha path to php